# Importing TypeScript external modules using aliases supplied through requirejs.config

Tags: requirejs, typescript

Here's my folder structure:

- app

  - app1

    - core.ts
  - app2

    - util.ts
  - packages

    - features

      - feature1

        - index.ts
  - app.ts (bootstraps the application)
  - main.ts (main entry point)
- vendor

  - requirejs (from https://requirejs.org)
- index.html

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test RequireJS with TypeScript</title>
    <script src="vendor/requirejs/require.js" data-main="app/main"></script>
  </head>
 <body>


 </body>
```

Notice in `paths`, I have added an alias for `feature1` as well. 
**main.ts**

```
'use strict';

require.config({
  paths: {
    app1: 'app1',
    app2: 'app2',
    feature1: 'packages/features/feature1'
  },
  deps: ['app']
});
```

**core.ts (app1)**

```
class Core {
  name = 'Core';
}

export = Core;
```

**util.ts (app2)**

```
class Util {
  name = 'Util';
}

export = Util;
```

**index.ts (feature1)**

```
class Util {
  name = 'Util';
}

export = Util;
```

From `app.ts`, I want to refer the `core.ts`, `util.ts` and `feature1's` `index.ts` files. This is how I attempted first and worked perfectly:

```
/// <amd-dependency path="feature1/index" name="Feature" />
declare var Feature: any;

import Core = require('app1/core');
import MyUtil = require('app2/util/myutil');

var c = new Core();
console.log(c.name);

var util = new MyUtil();
console.log(util.name);

var f = new Feature();
console.log(f.name);
```

Then I tried doing the following but failed. Seems like `require()` only understands relative path and it doesn't understands the aliases provided through `require.config(...)`:

```
import Core = require('app1/core');
import MyUtil = require('app2/util/myutil');
import Feature = require('feature1/index'); // ERROR!: Cannot find module `feature1/index`

var c = new Core();
console.log(c.name);

var util = new MyUtil();
console.log(util.name);

var f = new Feature();
console.log(f.name);
```

Is my understanding correct? Any best practice to refer other external modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code :

```
import Feature = require('feature1/index'); // ERROR!: Cannot find module `feature1/index`
```

This is a compiler error (requirejs is happy with it). *TypeScript* doesn't understand `requirejs.config` at the moment, so you must use *full relative paths*.

PS:This will be resolved soon though, see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5039 for details.